# Ionic 4 Navigate to page with new data

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-router

I have a home page that displays results based on some user information. From results page user can navigate to profile page and edit information. After edit information, they navigate back to home page. The problem is, the home page not refreshed with new results. It still shows old results. How can i reload this page with the new data.

**home.page.ts:**

```
openProfilePage() {
   this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
}
```

**profile.page.ts**

```
onSubmit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home'], {replaceUrl: true});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a call you need to make to update the info on:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  console.log('ionViewDidEnter ');
  // call update function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
ionViewWillEnter(){
  //here you check data is changed or not and call your function according to that this method call every time when navigate to home page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main interface for my app is dynamically built based upon whether or not the app has been activated. I created a previous route service that uses Angular’s Activated Route to detect if the main interface needs to be updated without doing a complete refresh.